# Editing Page Layout

Tags: page-layout, quick-edit, field-type

I have been given a test site to explore and perform some small tasks. As soon as I got it, I tried creating a new site and used a simple . There are several default pages, but isn't it possible to alter the size of the zones and relocate them wherever I want to?

Comment: I am working on SharePoint 2013. And chose the Publishing Site Template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a custom page layout based on your requirement by following the mentioned steps below :

- Browse to your publishing site.
- In the upper-right corner of the page, choose the gear icon, and then choose Design Manager.
- In Design Manager, in the left navigation pane, choose Edit Page Layouts.
- Choose Create a page layout.
- In the Create a Page Layout dialog box, enter a name for your page layout.
- Select a master page.
- Select a content type. The content type for this page layout determines what page fields will be available for this page layout in the Snippet Gallery.
- Choose OK.
- Click the link in the Status column to preview the file and to view any errors or warnings about the master page.
- To fix any errors, edit the HTML file that resides directly on the server by using an HTML editor to open and edit the HTML file in the mapped drive. Each time you save the HTML file, any changes are synced to the associated .aspx file.
- The preview of the page layout shows the page fields that were added automatically to the page layout. These page fields are site columns that are unique to the current content type. Now you are ready to style the page layout according to your original HTML mockups.

For more details check [Create a page layout in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822368.aspx)

You can also edit the current page layout in advanced mode (you should tack a backup before editing ) then try to change the divs as you like

```
 <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">-->
            <div>
                <!--CS: Start Page Field: Title Snippet-->
                <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldTextField" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="Publishing" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                <!--MS:<Publishing:EditModePanel runat="server" CssClass="edit-mode-panel">-->
                    <!--MS:<PageFieldTextField:TextField FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">-->
                    <!--ME:</PageFieldTextField:TextField>-->
                <!--ME:</Publishing:EditModePanel>-->
                <!--CE: End Page Field: Title Snippet-->
            </div>
            <div>
                <!--CS: Start Page Field: Page Image Snippet-->
                <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldRichImageField" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                <!--MS:<PageFieldRichImageField:RichImageField FieldName="3de94b06-4120-41a5-b907-88773e493458" runat="server">-->
                    <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><div id="ctl02_label" style="display:none">Page Image</div><div id="ctl02__ControlWrapper_RichImageField" class="ms-rtestate-field" style="display:inline" aria-labelledby="ctl02_label"><div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer"><div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Page Image</span></div><div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer"><div class="ms-rtestate-field"><img alt="" src="/_layouts/images/home.gif" style="BORDER: px solid; " /></div></div></div></div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
                <!--ME:</PageFieldRichImageField:RichImageField>-->
                <!--CE: End Page Field: Page Image Snippet-->
            </div>
        <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```

Check also [how to create a custom master page via Design Manager in SharePoint 2013](http://blog.navantis.com/creating-a-new-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 2):

no, there are several templates from which you can choose, I suppose you are watching the web part page. You did not specify which version you are using, you can also choose wiki pages to give you more flexibility

If you need another page layout you need to create a custom page layout and deploy it. It requires coding.